# What could cause WP-CLI search-replace to not replace all instances of a string?

Tags: wp-cli

We're migrating a site from dev to production using wp-cli to replace all occurrences in the database for the url, just like in the search-replace [example](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/search-replace/).  (http://example.dev to https://example.com)

`wp search-replace` finds and replaces all occurrences that it reported finding. However, there are still many lingering in the database, especially in serialized data. But, WP-CLI says that it handles serialized data as well.

If I run `wp db search 'http://example.dev' --all-tables` I get 20 more occurrences of the string. If I run `wp search-replace` with the `--all-tables` flag it still finds 0.

What could be causing it to not find these lingering instances of the string, and how I can also get them to be included in search-replace?

Comment: I can see the same thing when I use wp search-replace.

Comment: I'm running into this as well